# C's write() throughput inconsistency for larger buffer

Tags: c, file-io, benchmarking

I wrote a small program to measure the system time for C's `write()` call. I keep appending a buffer to a file until it reaches a certain file size. But for two different buffer sizes, I get drastically different numbers.

Here is a snippet of case #1:

```
char buffer1[] = malloc(4* 1024);
for(int i=0; i< 1048576; i++){
    int w = write(outputfile, buffer1, sizeof(buffer1));
}
```

Here is a snippet of case #2:

```
char buffer2[] = malloc(1024* 1024);
for(int i=0; i< 4096; i++){
    int w = write(outputfile, buffer2, sizeof(buffer2));
}
```

You can see in both cases the program writes 1048576x4kB = 4096x1024kB = ~4096 Mbytes of data to a file.

In my machine (8 gig ddr3 ram, core i7, 240gb ssd), case#1 takes 14.96 sys time to finish, giving me a throughput approx 274 MB/s.

Whereas case#2 takes 0.9 seconds sys time to finish, giving me a throughput approx 4551 MB/s.

There are some intermediate runs I did for some other buffer sizes, they also produce highly varying numbers.

I know a larger buffer size means less number of calls to `write()` function. But, isn't that each call should have taken longer, and eventually the overall time it takes to finish writing on file should be the same, regardless of buffer size? Why does the throughput vary so much for varying buffer sizes?

Here is the program:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Bj_CnO8DqFrOO3WwbsZbzFYjHLijTW7A/view?usp=sharing

Comment: It's not surprising that writing 4k at a time slows down from CPU overhead of making system calls, and other overhead in the kernel.  Although *that much* slowdown is surprising even on an Intel CPU with meltdown + spectre mitigation.

Comment: Your file size is only half your RAM size; write buffering in the kernel will make a *huge* difference.  If you run this twice back to back, the first write is probably still flushing to disk.  Are you at least using `sync` before / after each run?  (Also, don't put too much extra wear on your SSD with too much repetitive testing.)

Comment: Smells like a cacheing/buffering issue to me.  When the filesystem writes are split up, the system can start writing data to busses, controllers and'real' disk earlier, in parallel with the user buffer-filling and write calls.